# Empty Space - Additive Identity (Logic)

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

Why the empty space does not hold the additive identity property?

**Additive identity:** there exists an element 0 $\in$ V such that v + 0 = v for all v $\in$ V.

If there is no elements in V, I thought that this property should be vacuously true.

Comment: Because if $V$ is empty the formula $\exists 0 (0 \in V \land \ldots)$ will be false.

Comment: Any statement beginning "there exists" is vacuously **false** of an empty structure.